# Kivy3 Run a function when a object is clicked

Tags: python, 3d, kivy

I have an app where I have a renderer in a scatter, I need to know when someone clicks on the object but because the object is not directly under the camera, I don't know its X and Y coordinates, only its X, Y and Z. The camera is looking strait down and I have multiple movable objects so I need to be able to work it out on the go.

I tried using vectors and matrixes but the documentation was not to good so I had a lot of trouble with that. I also tried using maths -

```
bPos = obj.pos[0], obj.pos[1],  obj.pos[2]
bPos2 = .obj.pos[0] + 10, obj.pos[1] + 10., obj.pos[2] # I also don't know how to get the exact size so I tried this
cPos = self.camera.pos

pitch = atan((bPos[0] - cPos.x) / (bPos[1] - cPos.y))
yaw = atan((bPos[2] - cPos.z) / (bPos[1] - cPos.y))

x = width() / 2 + (pitch * (width() / self.camera.fov))
y = height() / 2 + (yaw * (height() / self.camera.fov))


pitch2 = atan((bPos2[0] - cPos.x) / (bPos2[1] - cPos.y))
yaw2 = atan((bPos2[2] - cPos.z) / (bPos2[1] - cPos.y))

x2 = width() / 2 + (pitch2 * (width() / self.camera.fov))
y2 = height() / 2 + (yaw2 * (height() / self.camera.fov))



with self.canvas.after: # To draw some points on so I know where it thinks the boundaries are
    Color(rgba=(0, 1, 0, 0.5))
    Rectangle(pos=(x, y), size=(10, 10))

    Color(rgba=(0, 0, 1, 0.5))
    Rectangle(pos=(x2, y2), size=(10, 10))
```

All my objects are 10 by 10 by 10. (-5 to 5)

The full project is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/GreenJon902/SpaceBuilderMergeGame) but it is a mess and quite large, the relevant part is at the bottom of [this file](https://github.com/GreenJon902/SpaceBuilderMergeGame/blob/master/graphics/customWidgets/baseLayout.py)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it, I did it with a Matrix.project(), I figured this out by going to OpenGL itself instead of kivy as openGl!

```
m = Matrix()

x, y, z = m.project(obj.pos[0]-5, obj.pos[1]-5, obj.pos[2]-5,
                    camera.model_matrix, camera.projection_matrix,
                    camera.pos.x, camera.pos.y, width, height)

x2, y2, z2 = m.project(obj.pos[0]+5, obj.pos[1]+5, obj.pos[2],
                       camera.model_matrix, camera.projection_matrix,
                       camera.pos.x, camera.pos.y, width, height)
```

I found the model and projection matrixes while looking through the kivy3 camera class.